# ACR1252U-M1 does not write information into txt files

Tags: nfc, acr

I am using nfc reader ACR1252U-M1. But when I put my card on it,reader does not write anything to a txt file but creates some device in the system( which deletes when card is removed from a reader).
Is there a way to make this reader write into a txt file, like usual readers do?

I tried different configuration tools, provided by acr but most of them just show errors like could not set UUId. I tried reinstalling drives, it did not help either